# Use of array.map and onchange in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mapping

The code below contains an `array.map` function what is the function of `term` and `i` and where was it gotten from, and what does the `array.map` and the `onchange` do

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Apps extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
}

iLikeFunctions() {
console.log('yay functions');
}

render() {

var array = ['here','we','go'];

var no = 'yes';
const display = 'My Name';

return (
  <div>
    <p>{display}</p>
    <hr />
    <input type="text" onChange={this.iLikeFunctions} />
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {array.map((term,i) => {
          no = 'no';
          return (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{term}</td>
              <td>{no}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
 );

  }
}

export default Apps;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Map:

The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. So in the following line:

```
array.map((term,i)
```

You are mapping the array called `array` and looping through the array, assigning the word `term` for each value in the array and return a `tr` element for each array element with their respective value, index and variable string printed on the `<tr>`.

### Key:

`i` is the index of the respective value which acts as a key since you didn't specify unique key ids for the elements.

A "key" is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements. Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

Do note that it is not recommended to use indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

Check out the `keys` section in the official [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for a more in-depth explanation of keys.

### onchange:

`onchange` watches the input field for any change and when it detects a change, it runs the `iLikeFunctions()`.

---

**tldr:** The above code loops through array `['here','we','go'];` and returns a `<tr>` for each value. It also runs the `iLikeFunctions()` whenever the input field value is changed.

Comment: Please what does the key do in <tr key={i}> @AndrewL