# how to add onchange event in react js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to `reactjs` I want to add `onchange` in my application. I am using map function for data.

```
onChange = (event,k,i) => {
     this.setState({

      dList: update(this.state.dList[k][i], {
        [event.target.name]:
          {$set: event.target.value} 
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Where do you want to add onChange event ?

Comment: <Input value={(data[1])}
                    name='Status'
                    onChange={event => this.onChange(event,i,1)}
                    //onChange={this.onChange(i,1)}
                    isEditable={this.state.isEditable}
                    transparent
                  />

Comment: i want to add onChange event table for editing data comes from url to my table

Answer (score 1):

state example

```
state = {
    name:'',
    password:''
}
```

Incase you have multiple inputs of example name and password

```
<input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />

<input type="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

this how you apply the onchange handler

```
handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put an `onChange` function in a `onChange` html tag attribute.

Example:

```js
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

[Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: i am using semantic ui react in my react application.this is my input tag<Input value={(data[1])} name='Status' onChange={event => this.onChange(event,i,1)} isEditable={this.state.isEditable} transparent />

Comment: @PiyushPandey here is an example of `map` and `onChange` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945554/use-of-array-map-and-onchange-in-react

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your component's state which depends on the previous state of the component, use the overloaded version of setState which takes a function as a parameter. This is because the calls made to the setState function are batched to improve performance.

```
onChange = (event,k,i) => {
     this.setState(prevState => {
      dList: update(prevState.dList[k][i], {
        [event.target.name]:
          {$set: event.target.value} 
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: when i am using onchange method i gives error =>TypeError: Cannot create property 'Status' on string 'C'.here Status is name in input and c is the value comes from url to my table